# Need Help in implementing total Hours, minutes, and seconds in PHP

Tags: php

I am quite new to PHP I need help in implementing the total Hours and minutes in PHP.

I have an array of time in PHP in hours, minutes and seconds

```
(array) Array
(
    [0] => 01:10:00
    [1] => 01:20:30
    [2] => 00:00:10
)
```

My Expected output should be the total time in Hours, minutes and seconds (ex. 2:30:40)

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours;
$minutes;
$seconds;

foreach( $thatArray as $v )
{
  $subArray = explode(':', $v);

  $hours   += $subArray[0];
  $minutes += $subArray[1];
  $seconds += $subArray[2];
}

// output $hours / $minutes / $seconds, correctly formatting, etc
```

Comment: @jalf: No problem, don't forget you can click the up arrow next to your answers to award the responders with points, and select a check next to the answer that you deem most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to give you the codez. here's how you can do it:

Get the individual components of the time using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Start by adding the seconds. If the result is greater than 60, increment minutes and so on.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal software developer. If you want pre-written code, go hire a freelance developer. Over here, we HELP YOU write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to convert all of them to a seconds representation, sum them, and convert them back. For example:

```
function timeToSeconds($time) {
    $parts = explode(':', $time);

    return $parts[0] * 3600 + $parts[1] * 60 + $parts[2];
}

function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60) % 60;
    $seconds %= 60;

    return str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$times = array('01:10:00', '01:20:30', '00:00:10');
$total = secondsToTime(array_sum(array_map('timeToSeconds', $times)));
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/LiktohG4)